# How to get server time not localtime in php

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

**First Part of the Question :**

When I m using `new Date ();` in Javascript.

it gives

```
Fri Jun 19 2015 11:18:02 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

This is giving my local machine time.whereas server time is 7 mins ahead.

Is there any function which gives server time not local machine time same exactly as `new Date()` But from server not localMachine.

In My project i am using codeigniter.is there any method to keep datetime same as servertime not localmachine time.

so when i use echo `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`. This gives server time.

**Second part of the question :**

How to echo date in php in the same format like `new Date()` in Javascript:

`new Date()` Prints `Fri Jun 19 2015 11:18:02 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`

But in Php `date('D M Y G:i:s T', time());` is giving `Fri Jun 19 2015 11:18:02 IST`

How to achieve same format like `new Date()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you work on real server I believe you can get proper time by this snippet.

```
function server_time()
{
  $this->load->helper('date');
  echo now();  
  echo "<br>";
}
```

If you use xampp or wamp on your local pc that time you'll get your local pc time.

Answer (score 1):

Create an ajax script which will retrieve server time

```
function server_time()
{
    $this->load->helper('date');
    echo now();  // UNIX timestamp
}
```

Then convert it in desired format with javascript

```
var date = new Date(response*1000);
```