# Time Difference between php and javascript

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is my code :

```
    function server_time()
    {
        $this->load->helper('date');            
        echo '<script>document.write((new Date())); </script>';
        echo '<br/>';           
        echo gmdate('D M d Y G:i:s T', time());

    }
```

Output is :

```
Fri Jun 19 2015 19:24:49 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
Fri Jun 19 2015 14:02:44 GMT
```

How to get same result below.

Comment: php will take your server date and js will take your system date.

Comment: Consider that one is the server-side time and one is the client-side time. If they're not matched you'll get differences. Even if they are perfectly synced on time you'll get differences because the client-side script will not run until after the server-side has finished responding to the request.

Comment: php uses seconds sincs 1970 and javascript miliseconds, so divide the number by 1000

Comment: then how to get server side time in javascript.is it possible ?

Comment: If you want server-side time witth JavaScript you have to use AJAX to get it.

Comment: Okay new Date() in js prints  Fri Jun 19 2015 11:18:02 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)    How we can get same format in php.This is not giving correct value date('D M Y G:i:s T')

Comment: My office colleque asked the same question here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30930848/how-to-get-server-time-not-localtime-in-php)

Comment: I have a question thats off topic. Why do people with good answers provide them here in the "comments" section rather than providing an actual answer below?

Comment: @CodeGodie - i think some people help other by heart coz they are developers and not for earning repu. or badges.

Comment: If the question can be answered in fewer characters than a typical tweet, then it's hardly worth answering, and simply putting it in the comments instead

Comment: gotcha, but does that mean the question always stays "unanswered" ?

Comment: when there is no answer i always search comment below the question on so.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Server Time when the page loads, and then count from then:

```
function server_time() {
    $this->load->helper('date');
    $sd = date('y, m, d, G, i, s, u');   
    echo '<script>var sd = new Date(' . $sd . ');</script>';
}
```

Your JS will now have a variable, `sd`, that is set to the same time as the server. You can now manipulate it as you would any other Date object.

EDIT

If this is not working, go to EPOCH.

```
function server_time() {
    $this->load->helper('date');
    $ts = time();   
    echo '<script>var sd = new Date(); sd.setTime(' . $ts . ');</script>';
}
```

Comment: This is the result **Tue Jul 20 1915 09:51:06 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)**  when server time is **Sat Jun 20 10:00:24 IST 2015**